# Suggested edit deleting the question in its entirety

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

My question arises  from  a new user (1 rep) asking  a [generic single-sentence question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21179746/1851270) (deeply downvoted),  where  a lengthy edit is suggested, completely rewriting the  original question  with detailed  examples.

More in general, say that a user asks a very generic question such as:
"*I am unable to catch errors in my Java code.  Can you explain how Java exception handling mechanism works?*"

Such a generic question would be downvoted up to the point it is deleted since too broad.
But, before this, assume a kind user suggests an edit where s/he completely rewrites the original question, making it into a pretty and interesting one, with specific code examples.

Complete rewrites might well occur to improve an interesting but badly posed question and [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476/233646) rule of the thumb is:

> You edit to make things better, clearer, more effective -- never to change meaning.

In this instance, it is quite an exercise of imagination to asses  what was the specific OP's problem and whether the edit complies to it. And, without  an instrument to remotely read OP's mind, we cannot prove the edit matched with their intended meaning.

Without such a proof, the edit is to be rejected and the original questions is doomed to be deleted.
Also there is the possibility that knowledgable users add  good answers to the very poor question (perhaps  possible good answers, given the broadness of the OP).

In these instances, we risk of throwing the baby out with the bathwater, that is,  we would remain with a deleted or anyway worthless question cluttering SO, while we might have had a pretty question with pretty answers.

What is, then,  the proper course of action here?

Comment: Weird, this question was asked on Jan. 17 204,  and the OP has no reputation history, and this question has a bounty - How is it possible?

Comment: @AlonEitan The bounty is from the user who suggested the edit, not from the user who asked it.

Comment: @Alon i'm more concerned about the date you posted, and will assume a typo in the year ;)

Comment: @Patrice Yeah, something definitely went wrong there

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the edit suggestion is based upon the comment that the OP placed below the answer. Even so, it's not clear to me if the edit is still within the OP's intention. That is the criterion on which it should be accepted or rejected. When in doubt, <kbd>Skip</kbd>.

On to the general case...

- If a question has an upvoted answer, it is less likely to be deleted. So value for the site remains.
- When you see a very generic question from a new user, it's probably been answered already in the past. So if you have some time to look for duplicates, see if you can find a duplicate, and close as duplicate.